# PHP, Javascript, Ajax passing parameters

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have php code that calls a javascript function:

```
onclick='fightit(0,0,0,0,0)'
```

Here is the javascript function:

```
function fightit(nbr,strt,bar,type,action) {
var params = "Nbr="+nbr;
params += "&Strt="+strt;
params += "&Bar="+bar;
params += "&FightType="+type;
params += "&Action="+action;
alert(params);
new Ajax.Updater('div01', 'php/fight.php', {method: 'get', parameters: params, onComplete: div05F});
}
```

When I call the function and display params I get;

```
Nbr=1&Strt=0&Bar=0&FightType=0&Action=0
```

This is what I'm suppose to get but when I use it in my php:

```
if (!isset($_GET['Action'])) {
    $_GET['Action'] = 0;
}
if (isset($_GET['FightType'])) {
   $fighttype = $_GET['FightType'];
}
else {
   $fighttype = 0; 
}
$s = $_GET['FightType'];
```

Action is set but FightType is not when I execute this line of code:

```
$s = $_GET['FightType'];
```

I get:

```
Undefined index: FightType in C:\wamp\www\hand\php\div08F.php on line 10
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: PHP can't call a javascript method directly, because PHP runs on server side and Javascript on client side.

Comment: Why are you setting the value of `$_GET['FightType']` to two variables (`$s` and `$fighttype`)?

Comment: does print_r($_GET) display what you expect?

Comment: Did you by chance try to print_r or var_dump $_GET at the beginning of your PHP script to make sure it's all there?

Comment: I set it to $s outside the if just to see what I was getting, that is the line where I get the error. I did a var_dump on $_GET['Action'] at the beginning of the PHP and that worked fine but when I did it on $_GET['FightType'] I get an undefined index. I'm not callin the javascript directly from the PHP, it's a response to the onClick event of a button I set up

Comment: Do a print_r on $_GET, not $_GET['Action'] or $_GET['FightType'] to see what's coming through.

Comment: just so you know, the alert is through javascript, so won't tell you anything on what gets sent to the php page. What page are you calling this javascript from? Give us a little more to go on, something is up with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT2: OK, with that information, I tested out. I think you are using one file, so I set up a mock php file to test things. I removed the onComplete and set a div with the update. Here is the result that works. Let me know if it helps:

```
<?php
if ( isset($_GET['Nbr']) ){
    // here Nbr is set, so we drop into outputting xml... you can do more before this
    // and you can open a separate file, but didn't know how things were set up for you.
    header('Content-Type: text/xml');
    $out = $_GET['Nbr'].','
        .(isset($_GET['Strt'])?$_GET['Strt']:'').','
        .(isset($_GET['Bar'])?$_GET['Bar']:'').','
        .(isset($_GET['FightType'])?$_GET['FightType']:'').','
        .(isset($_GET['Action'])?$_GET['Action']:'');
    print '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?'.'><span>'.htmlentities($out).'</span>';
    exit();
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fightit(nbr,strt,bar,type,action) {
    var params = "Nbr=" + nbr
        + "&Strt=" + strt
        + "&Bar=" + bar
        + "&FightType=" + type
        + "&Action=" + action;
    alert(params);

    // this is actually calling itself with '/t.php' and updating div01
    new Ajax.Updater('div01', '/t.php', {method: 'get', parameters: params});
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<table style="border-style:none;">
    <tr>
        <td style="border-style:none;">
            <input style="width:150px; text-align:center;" type="button" value="Steal" onclick="stealit()" />
        </td>
        <td id="fightBtn" style="border-style:none;"><input style="width:150px; text-align:center;" type="button" value="Fight" onclick="fightit(0,0,0,0,0)" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <div id="div01"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

ORIGINAL:

You are getting the fighttype error, because even though you check for it, you still use it after the check without rechecking (`$_GET['FightType']` still doesn't exist). Try this:

```
if (isset($_GET['FightType'])) {
   $fighttype = $_GET['FightType'];
}
else {
   $fighttype = 0; 
}
$s = $fighttype;
```

EDIT: to fix the ajax, try parameters like this (you might have to change the function variable names):

```
new Ajax.Updater('div01', 'php/fight.php', {method: 'get', parameters: {Nbr: nbr, Strt: strt, Bar: bar, FightType: type, Action: action}, onComplete: div05F})
```

Comment: I don't understand about the ?. My program has tons of Ajax calls that passes parameters and this is the first case where it doesn't work. The big question is why $_GET['FightType'] isn't set.

Comment: @S.e.Estes yeah, just noticed that. Can you pass back the _get array (and/or query string) as a string to javascript and output to see what is going on?

Comment: @S.e.Estes check the edit... that was how they set up parameters here: http://prototypejs.org/learn/introduction-to-ajax

Comment: I've never had to set up parameters like that in my other ajax calls. Why in this one instance would I have to do it differntly?

Comment: I changed my call to look like this:    new Ajax.Updater('div01', 'php/fight.php', {method: 'get', parameters: {Nbr: nbr, Strt: strt, Bar: bar, FightType: type, Action: action}, onComplete: div05F});    But is still blows up on FightType but not Action. Why would the other parameters pass correctly but not that one?

Comment: @S.e.Estes wait, the rest are working fine? So can you print out the query string to see what is being past so you can see what is making it rather than just the variables... Plus we probably need to see more code if others are working fine, but this isn't. There is something else up here. Can we at least see the code that sets all the php variables? Plus, can you send back the query string as a variable to see what it looks like?

Comment: How do I print out the whole query string? I'm rather new to PHP and Javascript

Comment: I figured it out. Here's what I get:          'REQUEST_METHOD' => string 'GET' (length=3)
          'QUERY_STRING' => string 'Nbr=[object%20Object]&Strt=null&Bar=undefined&Type=undefined&Action=1' (length=69)
          'REQUEST_URI' => string '/hand/php/div08F.php?Nbr=[object%20Object]&Strt=null&Bar=undefined&Type=undefined&Action=1' (length=90)

Comment: change the complete (which is something I'm not sure of) to `onComplete: function(transport){ var h = transport.responseXML; [put h into a div or something] }`

on the php side only print out the xml response with the query string

Comment: @S.e.Estes hmm, so you aren't simply calling it with `onclick='fightit(0,0,0,0,0)'` as you said unless it's being called somewhere else. I looked it up and it should accept the string params, so why are you getting Type instead of FightType? what aren't you showing us in the code? Did you try it with the array?

Comment: Here is the code section, sorry I left it out.  echo "<table style='border-style:none;'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td style='border-style:none;'><input style='width:150px; text-align:center;' type='button' value='Steal' onclick='stealit()' /></td>";
echo "<td id='fightBtn' style='border-style:none;'><input style='width:150px; text-align:center;' type='button' value='Fight' onclick='fightit(0,0,0,0,0)' /></td>";

Comment: hmm, so why is the alert: `Nbr=1&Strt=0&Bar=0&FightType=0&Action=0`... maybe you just typed it out and misses a 0 for nbr... Either way, did you try with an array?

Comment: Does it help to say that I'm using Prototype version 1.7 for my Ajax calls? Sorry I left that out.

Comment: I just mistyped on the alert Nbr=0. I'll try the array.

Comment: In the JS I tried this:

var params = new Array();
params[0] = nbr;
params[1] = strt;
params[2] = bar;
params[3] = type;
params[4] = action;
new Ajax.Updater('div01', 'php/fight.php', {method: 'get', parameters: params, onComplete: div05F});

Then in in Php I did this:

var_dump(get_defined_vars());
And I got this: Request-URI Too Large
 
The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity limit for this server.

Comment: Made a Mistake in my js, here is what I have: var p = new Array();
p[0] = nbr;
p[1] = strt;
p[2] = bar;
p[3] = type;
p[4] = action;
var params="Param="+p; new Ajax.Updater('div01', 'php/fight.php', {method: 'get', parameters: params, onComplete: div05F});  I get this as though: 'QUERY_STRING' => string 'Nbr=[object%20Object]&Strt=null&Bar=undefined&Type=undefined&Action=1' (length=69)
          'REQUEST_URI' => string '/hand/php/div08F.php?Nbr=[object%20Object]&Strt=null&Bar=undefined&Type=undefined&Action=1' (length=90)
     This makes no sense.

Comment: @S.e.Estes I loaded prototype and ran on one page to see how it ran and it worked for me. I was trying to figure out your setup, but really doesn't matter that much as long as you can see what is happening. So check edited code above.

Comment: Now I'm wondering if it's something with my browser? I can't set a cookie either.

Comment: Cookies are a different matter, let's do this one at a time. Did this work for you? If it did update your code and get it working. Then create a new post for cookies. .. when you create a new post for cookies try to show as much code as possible and what you are using and explain what you are trying to do and what you have tried. Plus, accepting answers helps others to want to help you as well.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean to bring up cookies here but I was just wondering if the problem was with my browser. Because I got rid of passing Nbr, Strt, Bar, Type, Action seperately and instead am passing Param=0,0,0,0,0 but my query string when I print it out in PHP is: string 'Nbr=[object%20Object]&Strt=null&Bar=undefined&Type=undefined&Action=1' (length=69)
  I accept all answers and have tried to make everyting work but to no avail. Of all my Ajax calls set up the exact same way it mystifies me why this one instance is going so haywire.

Comment: How are you printing out php? It should be going through ajax so if you open it separately, then something is odd (unless you are just testing the xml)... can you put in your original post (please don't put too much code in the comments) your entire (or dumbed down as small as you can get) php/html file with the html and the php file you are calling with ajax?

Comment: here is the link to my code, as you can see the problem starts at the very beginning [link](http://hand.seestes.com/div08FTEST.txt)

Comment: Actually I linked to the wrong program. here is the one being called from Ajax [link](http://hand.seestes.com/fight.txt)

Comment: @S.e.Estes wow, what a mess.. You can probably use update instead of delete and insert (for mysql) in many places. There has got to be a better way to design a cleaner flow to this, but lets just get it working... I don't see where you are submitting.. where is the js or header? I see where you are receiving.

Comment: @S.e.Estes oh, wait... I see it... hold one

Comment: As you can see, I've taken on the ambitious project of writing a games using php, js, and mysql when I know very little about any of them :( It's turning out to be a pretty cool RPG, though

Comment: When you tested the new js did you make sure to clear the cache (I think ctrl-5f does it)? if you did, what changed in the header?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about what changed in the header? Before I tested the new js I did clear the cache by going into internet options and clearing that way but the old query string got sent back, not the new one. I tried ctrl-f5 too but that didn't work either

Comment: Problem solved! Turns out the onComplete in my Ajax call was screwing things up. Thank you all so much for helping out, your answers pointed me in the right direction. Before today I didn't even know what a query string was or how to display it. You've been very patient with a novice. Thanks!!

Comment: @S.e.Estes oh, np. If you have the solution, either post a new answer with it and accept it or accept one of the current answers and update your post with the solution so if anyone does a search they can see what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
function fightit(nbr,strt,bar,type,action) {
    var params = "{Nbr:" + nbr + ",Strt:" + strt + ",Bar:" + bar + "FightType:" + type + ",Action:" + action}";
    etc...
```

EDIT: OK, this is essentially the same as craniumonempty's suggestion, which was posted before mine.

EDIT: For the sake of completeness, and in response to craniumonempty's comment: This should probably rather (and simpler) be:

```
var params = {Nbr:nbr, Strt:strt, Bar:bar, FightType:type, Action:action};
```

Comment: would it work that way? I thought it would have to be something like: `var params = {Nbr: nbr, Strt: strt, Bar: bar, FightType: type,Action: action};`

Comment: @craniumonempty:I think you are right, it probably shouldn't be a string, it should be an associative array.

Comment: That doesn't work either. The alert seems to show the parameters passing correctly though

Comment: @S.e.Estes: Just to check, replace 'get' with 'post' and see if that makes a difference?

Comment: I tried var_dump on all the parameters I'm passing and none are passing correctly, it was just a coincidence that Action was set

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Ajax prototype, try to use jQuery.ajax:

```
function fightit(nbr,strt,bar,type,action) {
    jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'php/fight.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {'Nbr': nbr, 'Strt': strt, 'Bar': bar, 'FightType': type, 'Action': action}
    });
}
```